# Json to Double type JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am trying to get data from json to variables.One of variable is type of double but its getting 0.0 values.I tried some solution but they did'nt work.

This is my json:
 {"unitfactor":"0.1","unit":"N","canvassize":{"height":"302","width":"412"}

Code:

```
final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(fbeInput);
double mUnitFactor = jObject.getDouble("unitfactor");
String unit = jObject.getString("unit");
```

But mUnitFactor always gets 0.0 value.
Even if i try to fetch unitfactor as string it did'nt show any value during debugging.

```
String mUnitFactor = jObject.getString("unitfactor");
```

Comment: post your json too

Comment: unitfactor looks like string. try `Double.parseDouble(fbeObject.getString("unitfactor)`

Comment: remove double quotation mark.

Comment: can you retrieve the value of 'unit'?

Answer (score 2):

```
"{"unitfactor":"0.1","unit":"N"}"
```

its because your unitfactor **0.1** is String in the making.
change it to this:

```
"{"unitfactor":0.1,"unit":"N"}"
```

Remove the double quotation mark on `0.1`.

or try to use the approach of @iNan:

```
double mUnitFactor = Double.parseDouble(fbeObject.getString("unitfactor"));
```

In this approach, you will first get the String unitfactor value, which is `0.1`, and then you will parse it to Double using its wrapper class.

Comment: I cannot change json its coming from an api.Is there a way to remove quatation in java.

Answer (score 1):

Since unitfactor is of type string, If you cannot change JSON then you can use

`double mUnitFactor = Double.parseDouble(fbeObject.getString("unitfactor"))`

Comment: it did'nt work i have updated the question please check.

Comment: Which json library are u using?

Comment: import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject

Comment: I am able to get result using the same library. I could see you have two JSONObject `jObject ` and `fbeObject` are you referring to correct one?

Comment: it was a written mistake,all of them is jobject.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unit for varaibles in json.
for string use "" , double inverted and for numeric like double,float, long directly assign value

in your case:

```
{"unitfactor": 0.1, "unit": "N"}
```